# JQuery UI Dialog and OnClick event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a JQuery UI Dialog which I have put an ASP.NET button on.  I need to be able to call a server side OnClick event from this, but it is never called.  Here is my Dialog, can somebody help?

```
<div id="dialogWrapper" runat="server">
    <div style="height: auto; width: auto;" id="dialog">
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <td width="300px" valign="top">
                    Current Documents :
                </td>
                <td width="300px" valign="top">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Upload Document :
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr /><tr />
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:FileUpload id="fileUploadControl" runat="server" Width="200px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr /><tr />
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button  ID="btnUploadFile" runat="server" OnClick="btnUploadFile_Click" Text="Upload File" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT : Here is how the dialog is being created :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#<%=dialogWrapper.ClientID %>').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 250,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        title: "Upload/Open Files",
        show: "drop"
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you show how you create the dialog? Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568784/jquery-modal-form-dialog-postback-problems/608215#608215), there might be your answer.

Answer (score 4):

jQueryUI puts the Dialog box outside of the ASP.NET `Form` tag and so your button won't register. Try appending the dialog to the Form tag like so:

```
    $('#divDialog').dialog({
     //your normal dialog settings...


      open: function(type,data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
      }
    });
```

From [this post](http://www.keysolutions.com/blogs/kenyee.nsf/d6plinks/KKYE-7XPVS6).