# Submit ASP.NET Form within Jquery Remodal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, remodal

I've created an ASP.NET web page (.aspx) which is using a Jquery plugin containing a subscription form.

The modal containing the form pops with no problems or errors, but the problem is when I complete the form with data and press the submit button, the form doesn't post back so the C# in codebehind can't process the the form data.

This is the JQuery Modal Plugin: http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/

**Here is the ASP.NET page code:**

```
<a href="#" data-remodal-target="modal" class="action-button">Get Free Trial</a>

<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxFirstName" runat="server" />

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxLastName" runat="server" />

    <label>Email</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmail" runat="server" />

    <asp:button runat="server" ID="ActiveCampaignSend" Text="Subscribe" OnClick="FormSubmit_Click"/>
</div>
```

**Sample of the C# Code Behind:**

```
 protected void FormSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // Code thate processes the form goes here....
 }
```

I've tested the form witout using the Jquery ReModal and it submits and works perfectly. I would try and not use a Modal window but my client has specifically requested it happens this way.

If someon can help me fix this issue, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: Did you end up using the remodal plugin to solve your issue? I am stuck in the exact same situation.

Answer (score 0):

The remodal plugin uses your `<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal">` as a prototype to build the dom elements for the modal window. When it does this, it appends them to the `body`, outside the `form` tag.
Thats why they dont interact with your form and you dont get a postback

When your `asp:button` is clicked, copy the values of email, first and last name inputs to the inside the form and then call `submit` on the `form`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found the following solution which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, I found this post which fixed the issue:

[jQuery modal form dialog postback problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568784/jquery-modal-form-dialog-postback-problems?rq=1)

Comment: what part specifically in that post did you use to fix the problem? did you stop using remodal and start using the jqueryui modal?