# No postback after user confrim in jquery dialog box

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am newsiest on jQuery. I need to show the  dialog box to get the user response. If the use click confirm, I need to update the database on sever. I found the example [jQuery dialog Confirm-JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/nvZc4/) and followed the code. However, after the user click confirm, it is not postback to server. Would someone tell me how to fix it.

There is my jQuery script code:

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   modal: true
               });
           });

           $(function() {

               $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                   autoOpen: false,
                   modal: true,
                   buttons : {
                       "Confirm" : function() {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                           return true;        
                       },
                       "Cancel" : function() {
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                           return false;
                       }
                   }
               });

               $("#Button1").on("click", function(e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
               });

           });
```

There is the code on vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
End Sub
```

There is the button on aspx page

```
  <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server"  text="test" visible="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just need one step to do postback by using `appendTo` function to bind with target form:

```
$("#Button1").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");  
    $("#dialog-confirm").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
});

<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"  text="test" visible="true" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Of course, if you're using dynamic client ID (without `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute at `asp:Button`), you need to use `ClientID` instead of button's server ID:

```
$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
    $("#dialog-confirm").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
});
```

Or you can embed `appendTo` into `dialog` setting (with jQuery 1.10 and above):

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons : {
        "Confirm" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return true;        
        },
        "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return false;
        }
    },
    appendTo: "form" // append this setting
});
```

If `appendTo` doesn't work with your page, try `__doPostBack` method (but not guaranteed to work with all browsers):

```
__doPostBack('<%= Button1.UniqueID %>', '');
```

Similar issues:

[jQuery UI Dialog with ASP.NET button postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757232/jquery-ui-dialog-with-asp-net-button-postback)

[jQuery modal form dialog postback problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568784/jquery-modal-form-dialog-postback-problems)